# How can I add the constraint to input statement in python

Tags: python-3.x

As you can see i am trying to check if the entered input by the user is string or not. If not, I have to display invalid name.

```
student_name = input("Enter the name of the student")
x = type(student_name)
if x!=str:
    print('invalid name')
else:
    print(student_name)
```

Comment: try `if x!='str':` instead of `if x!=str:`

Comment: The return value of `input` is **always** a string. There is no need to check that.

Answer (score 0):

```
student_name = input("Enter the name of the student")

try:
    int(student_name)
    print('invalid name')
except ValueError:
     print(student_name)
```

or

```
import re

student_name = input("Enter the name of the student")

num_format = re.compile(r'^\-?[1-9][0-9]*$')
for c in student_name:
    it_is = re.match(num_format,c)
    if it_is: it_is = True
if it_is:
    print('invalid name')
else:
    print(student_name)
```

the difference is on the first one you can pass through numbers with characters (more like username) but second one you should enter only characters.